# Error while trying to run sass --watch from terminal

Tags: css, terminal, sass

I'm working on a small project right now and I'm using sass as my preprocessor. Up until today, it's been working just fine. However now when I run the command sass --watch app.sass:main.css in my projects style folder, it might compile my sass into the css file once before I get this error:

```
fsevent_watch[1139] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
```

I have never had this happen before, and I'm at a loss for what to do. I can only get it to compile my sass to css once before it gives this error and then stops entirely.

Any ideas of what I can do to solve this?

Comment: This on shared hosting?  You're certain nothing has changed since yesterday?  Ruby Sass (because I can't find anything in the Sass repo that matches any of those function/method names)?

Comment: This is just on localhost. All I really did was open up my project and run the watch command again. I have no idea what's changed at all but it pops this error about five seconds after I run the command

Comment: What do you mean by "open up my project"?